# Different profiles for different guilds

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord, discord.py

How can I make different playerinfo on different guilds?
My code was originally for a single server. But now I need to do for more. I tried to make a check via WHERE AND, but it didn't work.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="!help"))
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT,
        exp INT,
        hp INT,
        mana INT,
        maxattack INT,
        minattack INT,
        server_id INT
    )""")
```

```
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id} AND server_id = {guild.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100, 30, 50, 39, {guild.id})")
                connection.commit()
            else:
                pass
```

playerinfo:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['playerinfo'])
async def __playerinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Характеристики пользователя **{ctx.author}** 
            Репутация: **{cursor.execute("SELECT rep FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id} AND server_id = {ctx.guild.id}").fetchone()[0]}**
            Уровень: **{cursor.execute("SELECT lvl FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Кол-во опыта: **{cursor.execute("SELECT exp FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Кол-во хп: **{cursor.execute("SELECT hp FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Кол-во маны: **{cursor.execute("SELECT mana FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Кол-во денег: **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Максимальная Атака: **{cursor.execute("SELECT maxattack FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            Минимальная Атака: **{cursor.execute("SELECT minattack FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**
            """
        ))
```

As you can see, I tried, but it didn't work(

Answer (score 0):

There 2 very common ways of storing data for multiple servers, class storing, and a JSON file. First I'm going to show you how to store and recall data using class storing. You want to create a dictionary to store the class sessions as well as a class to store data. Please note that all of the data is lost when the script is restarted using this method.

```
playerinfo = {}

class Player:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable
```

Then you can add the data to the dictionary whenever you join a server.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    playerinfo[guild.id] = Player(variable)
```

Now you can call that for the specific guild anywhere!

```
@client.command()
async def getplayerinfo(ctx):
    info = playerinfo[ctx.guild.id].variable
    await ctx.send(f"Player info: {info}")
```

The second option is to store your data using a JSON file. Just be sure you have the JSON module imported into your script! You can just create a new TXT file with the following contents.

```
{playerinfo: []}
```

Now you can add your guild id whenever you join a guild.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("data.txt") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    data["playerdata"].append({
    "id" = guild.id,
    "variable" = variable
})
    
    with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Now we're able to call that data from anywhere!

```
@client.command()
async def getplayerinfo(ctx):
    with open("data.txt") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    for guild in data["playerdata"]:
        if guild["id"] == ctx.guild.id:
            info = guild["variable"]
            await ctx.send(f"Player info: {info}")
```

I know this was a fairly long post, but nobody said this kind of thing was a short process. If you have any questions feel free to comment on this post, don't worry I'll see it!